# SQLAlchemy query to find and replace a substring if it exists in a column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a query in SqlAlchemy to find and replace a substring with another string if it exists in a column. What is the best way to achieve this?

I am trying to use `regexp_replace`. I am unable to figure out how to use it. What I have tried so far is:

```
regexp_statement = table.select(sqlalchemy.func.regexp_replace(*regexp))
```

But this translates into wrong sql query. `Select * from table_name where regexp_replace(string, search_string, replace_string)`

How to properly use regexp_replace in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You need to use `update`, not `select`. Try to use this:

```
replace_func = sqlalchemy.func.regexp_replace(
    table.c.column,
    your_string_to_replace,
    your_string_to_replace_with
)
table.update(values={table.c.column: replace_func})
```

**OLD**

You can use raw sql for that:

```
sql_expr = (
    "update {table} set {field} = " +
    "replace({field}, {str_to_repl}, {str_to_repl_with});"
).format(
    table=your_table_name,
    field=your_field_name,
    str_to_repl=your_string_to_replace,
    str_to_repl_with=your_string_to_replace_with,
)
session.execute(sql_expr)
session.commit()
```

Comment: But I have to do it in sqlalchemy.

Comment: -1 for string formatting SQL queries instead of using proper [placeholders](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) and bound params.